# Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\fileName' is denied

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I want to create a csv file and save it in a particular folder.  My code is as below:

```
string Name = UserID + "HistoricalRecords.csv";
string fileName = "C:\\Temp\\"+Name;
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("fileName");
```

However, I am still getting the above error.  I am not saving the file to that path though.  Any idea as to why I am getting this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: try running VS as administrator

Comment: @DieterB that's quite a "big gun" for a simple error like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring literally here:

```
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("fileName");
```

and, because there is no full path given, it goes to the current working directory, which happens to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\`

you should use the variable name:

```
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName);
```